# MYSQL | PHP-MySQLi-Database-Class | Subquery

Tags: php, mysql, subquery, php-mysqlidb

I want help in forming this query using class object wrapper(MysqliDb ). [You can find here (MysqliDb )](https://github.com/ThingEngineer/PHP-MySQLi-Database-Class#subqueries)

This is the query i needed to convert

```sql
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM users WHERE eventId=34) as t2 WHERE name like "alex" or email like "alex";
```

**For Example**

```php
    $db = getDbInstance();
    $db->where('eventId', 34);
    $status = $db->get('users');
//SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE eventId=34
```

Comment: Why have the subquery? Isn't `SELECT * FROM users WHERE eventId=34 and (name like "alex" or email like "alex")` the same? Please tag the library you are using, and add any errors you are receiving.

Comment: Why are you using this ancient library? I don't think it's maintained anymore

Comment: @Dharman then library would be good for PHP

Comment: @user3783243 no, its now fetching required rows and i want form using this library PHP-MySQLi

Answer (score 1):

I found it this works, by using `Having`

```php
    $db = getDbInstance();
    $db->having('eventId', 34);
    $db->where('name', '%' . $search . '%', 'like');
    $db->orwhere('email', '%' . $search . '%', 'like');
    $status = $db->get('users');
```